# How can I put the contents of Layout 1 as the background of Layout 2?

Tags: java, android-studio

In the first layout, several text views and image views are set. How can I set the background of the second layout with the image I capture from the first layout by clicking a button?

Answer (score 0):

I used this code

```
binding.cardLAYOUT.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
binding.cardLAYOUT.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = 
Bitmap.createBitmap(binding.cardLAYOUT.getWidth(), 
binding.cardLAYOUT.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
Drawable bgDrawable = binding.cardLAYOUT.getBackground();
bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
binding.cardLAYOUT.draw(canvas);
BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
binding.cardbacklayout.setBackground(drawable);
```